# What is correct modprobe.d logic?

Tags: rhel7, modprobe, rhel9

I have two different systems, rhel7 and rhel9. I've been curiously looking at CIS benchmarks for both of these. However, when it comes to disable kernel modules I get confused.

When I look at CIS for rhle7 they advice to put `install <MODULE> /bin/true` in a `modprobe.d/<MODULE>` file.

For RHEL9 it seems to be `install <MODULE> /bin/false`. However, if I look at `ansible-lockdown` on Github for inspiration they use following option for Rhel9: `install <MODULE> /bin/true` ([Ansible-lockdown)](https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/RHEL9-CIS/blob/devel/templates/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf.j2)

Please help me understand the difference and what's the correct usage.

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone attempts to load these modules anyway?

Comment: Honestly, now I just try to understand the CIS benchmarks when it comes to hardening my systems, and especially the modprobe stuff.  It's related to a class I have.

Comment: `/bin/true` is the correct usage (but it still "hack-ish" IMO): https://serverfault.com/questions/1021783/why-bin-true-in-modprobe-conf